# In Azure function with proxy, get original URL

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I am setting up an Azure function app where I'm proxying all requests for a subdomain to one specific function.  My `proxies.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "Root URI to Trigger Function": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "/{*path}",
        "methods": [
          "GET",
          "POST"
        ]
      },
      "backendUri": "http://example.com/api/myfunc"
    }
  }
}
```

Inside my `myfunc` function, I'm trying to access the URL of the original request using `req.originalUrl` - however it's always set to `http://example.com/api/myfunc`.

I tried adding request override to add an extra header, something like this:

```
"requestOverrides": {
  "backend.request.headers.X-Original-URL": "{request.originalUrl}"
}
```

Yet, this doesn't work and the `X-Original-Url` header contains `\n\u000fx-forwarded-for\u0012\texample.com` value

How can I reliably get the original URL that my function app received?

Comment: I imagine that setting up X-Forwarded-* headers could do the trick but I really haven't tried it on Azure https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge But what do I set it to?

Comment: Can you check if this article may be helpful: https://github.com/watson/original-url

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge thanks, but unfortunately no, as azure proxy does not set any of the X-Forwarded-... headers

Comment: But apparently the originalUrl has the header information like you said "\n\u000fx-forwarded-for\u0012\texample.com". Can't you just pass that in the header and then access it on your function?

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge I have no idea where that is coming from.  My original URL was `http://example.com/abc` - this is what I want to get inside the function.

Comment: Issue was discusses here too: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1500 Despite that you can try to define your own customer header (as suggested above) and take the value from `{request.headers.host}` (or introduce an additional query parameter you catch up in your function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the original intent of `originalUrl` was exactly this, to preserve the original URL as called by the user. This is how it would work if we really dealt with a node.js application without any MS proxies on it, but possible with rewrites.

So in my case I had to use `requestOverrides` and custom headers to give me what I need.  My `proxies.json` now has this:

And in my function, I can reconstruct the URL this way:

```
let origHost = req.headers.hasOwnProperty('x-original-host') ? req.headers['x-original-host'] : req.headers['host'];
let origPath = req.headers.hasOwnProperty('x-original-path') ? req.headers['x-original-path'] : ''
let search = new URL(req.url).search;

let originalUrl = 'https://' + origHost + '/' + origPath + (search ? '?' : '') + search;
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to get the original protocol (http vs https), but in my case it doesn't matter, because I'm using https everywhere anyway.

Comment: Hey there, I think you forgot to paste the contents of your `proxies.json` file... I'm looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

See this GitHub issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1500

We can pass original "Host" header to our backend with `requestOverrides`:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "chandler-function-proxy-app1": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/{*proxyPath}"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://localhost/entry",
            "requestOverrides": {
                "backend.request.headers.X-ORIGINAL-HOST": "{request.headers.host}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we also captured the original `pathname` with `/{*proxyPath}`, so we can get

- Original `pathname` by `context.req.params.proxyPath`
- Original `Host` by `context.req.headers["x-original-host"]`