# How to pass proxy URL to the machine behind that proxy?

Tags: mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee

Our server setup is the following:

a proxy and load balancer directs all the requests to its machines behind. The problem is, that these machines behind do not know where they are. If the proxy gets the request for

```
www.bridge.de/m01
```

he redirects to machine01.
Machine01 only knows its local path

```
m01
```

For an application solution for a password reset functionality I considered several opportunities.
We decided to pass the value of URL from 'before proxy' to the database of machine01. So machine01 'knows' its external context for that specific requests.

My question is: Is there a better way to pass external URL context to machines behind a proxy? We are using JavaEE, JSP and MySql for our application. Virtual machines running with CentOS.

Thanks for any suggestions! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not fully clear.
I assume you have the issue, what your load balancer terminates the connection and forwards you the request.
Usually your balancer provides you the origin URL of the request, since you may need it from time to time.
In this case you can check your http headers. If it is not provided, you have to reconfigure your balancer to provide you the needed details.

check this: [Strategies for dealing with URIs when building an application that sits behind a reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923151/strategies-for-dealing-with-uris-when-building-an-application-that-sits-behind-a)